# c program to save the ipconfig in a file

Tags: c, console, text-files

I have the following code, is it possible to store the `ipconfig` result in a file. Please help me with this

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
   return 0;
}
```

the `ipconfig` results to be saved to a text file called `ip.txt`  Please help me with this. THANKS in ADVANCE

Comment: have you tried the same for your code ?

Comment: yes, i have tried for my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig > myfile.txt");
```

**Edit:**

If you want both `stdout` and `stderr` placed in the file (thanks to and upon comment of @user3629249) :

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig 2>&1 myfile.txt");
```

**Edit 2:**

If you want to know more about redirection, check the microsoft's [redirection operators tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspxhttps://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: He can just simply write that on a console window... Using `system()` on such a simple case is not worth the effort of compiling

Comment: @rlam12: exactly! i thought the same thing. why would he even do that? But i'm not here to judge. The question was clear enough and i just gave the answer.

Comment: the `>` should be `2>&1` so both stderr and stdout are placed into the file

Answer (score 0):

This will write the output to a file.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig > /path/to/file 2>&1");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not correct.   the inclusion of stderr with stdout needs to be at the original 'redirection' operator, not after the file name

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect the output to your file. Note that `ipconfig.exe` is on a **path**

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("ipconfig > ip.txt");
    return 0;
}
```